# Lack of diversification, is it really a drawback of Genetic Algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, heuristics, evolutionary-algorithm

We know that Genetic Algorithms (or evolutionary computation) work with an encoding of the points in our solution space Ω rather than these points directly. In the literature, we often find that GAs have the drawback : (1) since many chromosomes are coded into a similar point of Ω or similar chromosomes have very different points, the efficiency is quite low. Do you think that is really a drawback ? because these kind of algorithms uses the mutation operator in each iteration to diversify the candidate solutions. To add more diversivication we simply increase the probability of crossover. And we mustn't forget that our initial population ( of chromosones ) is randomly generated ( another more diversification). The question is,  if you think that (1) is a drawback of GAs, can you provide more details ? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mutation and random initialization are not enough to combat the problem that is known as *genetic drift* which is the major problem of genetic algorithms. Genetic drift means that the GA may quickly lose most of its genetic diversity and the search proceeds in a way that is not beneficial for crossover. This is because the random initial population quickly converges. Mutation is a different thing, if it is high it will diversify, true, but at the same time it will prevent convergence and the solutions will remain at a certain distance to the optimum with higher probability. You will need to adapt the mutation probability (not the crossover probability) during the search. In a similar manner the Evolution Strategy, which is similar to a GA, adapts the mutation strength during the search.

We have developed a variant of the GA that is called OffspringSelection GA (OSGA) which introduces another selection step after crossover. Only those children will be accepted that surpass their parents' fitness (the better, the worse or any linearly interpolated value). This way you can even use random parent selection and put the bias on the quality of the offspring. It has been shown that this slows the genetic drift. The algorithm is implemented in our framework [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com). It features a GUI so you can download and try it on some problems.

Other techniques that combat genetic drift are niching and crowding which let the diversity flow into the selection and thus introduce another, but likely different bias.

EDIT: I want to add that the situation of having multiple solutions with equal quality might of course pose a problem as it creates neutral areas in the search space. However, I think you didn't really mean that. The primary problem is genetic drift, ie. the loss of (important) genetic information.

Answer (score 0):

As a sidenote, you (the OP) said:

> We know that Genetic Algorithms (or evolutionary computation) work with an encoding of the points in our solution space Ω rather than these points directly.

This is not always true. An individual is coded as a **genotype**, which can have any shape, such as a string (genetic algorithms) or a vector of real (evolution strategies). Each genotype is transformed into a **phenotype** when assessing the individual, i.e. when its **fitness** is calculated. In some cases, the phenotype is identical to the genotype: it is called **direct coding**. Otherwise, the coding is called **indirect**. (you may find more definitions [here (section 2.2.1)](http://francky.me/doc/mrf2011-HEC-ISIR-ENS_en.pdf))

*Example of direct encoding:* 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroevolution#Direct_and_Indirect_Encoding_of_Networks

*Example of indirect encoding:* 
Suppose you want to optimize the size of a rectangular parallelepiped dened by its length, height and width. To simplify the example, assume that these three quantities are integers between 0 and 15. We can then describe each of them using a 4-bit binary number. An example of a potential solution may be to genotype 0001 0111 01010. The corresponding phenotype is a parallelepiped of length 1, height 7 and width 10.

Now back to the original question on diversity, in addition to what DonAndre said you could read you read chapter 9 "*Multi-Modal Problems and Spatial Distribution*" of the excellent book [Introduction to Evolutionary Computing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642072852) written by A. E. Eiben and J. E. Smith. as well as a research paper on that matter such as [Encouraging Behavioral Diversity in Evolutionary Robotics: an Empirical Study](http://www.isir.upmc.fr/files/2011ACLI2061.pdf). **In a word, diversity is not a drawback of GA, it is "just" an issue.**